# What can I do if my MacBook isn’t charging but already ran out?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery, repair

My 12" 2017 MacBook suddenly stopped charging, and I tried an SMC reset. However, the MacBook already ran out on the battery, and thus I think even the SMC reset did not work, since when I did it, it was just that the battery icon flashed, yet it didn’t start at all.

Unfortunately, I live in a city where there is no Genius Bar, and I stay here for a few more months. Is there anything I can do to make the charge work?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3915022

Comment: Which model is yours?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii 2017 MacBook (12’)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you saw the power light flash when you reset the SMC, that indicates the reset is done and successful and you can move on to the rest of the steps in the guide.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267

I would let it charge up for 1 hour and then run through the steps above before getting on with Apple Support to see what the cost for battery service with mail in so you can then decide to go with Apple or look locally for an authorized or non-authorized repair. Apple will be able to refer you to their consultants that are certified / local (or as remote as you are if that’s the case).

I’ve had them overnight a box, get it in the mail, send out the machine and get it back a day later. I’m in a big city, though but mail-in is almost always faster than the Genius Bar for me these days. Even for battery service. Getting the machine to the parts is easier and cheaper than making an appointment and the stores often just send these out so you don’t save time for this repair.

Good luck - be sure to make an answer with what you do - the above is general advice and might or might not be the best for you.

There is almost always enough residual power a day or two after the machine shuts off for a SMC reset and if the battery goes completely flat, that too resets the SMC in a way since it cold starts when the trickle charge returns. Also, be sure you can’t try a different charger if it’s just that.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a “power light” on the 2017 MacBook.

Try connecting the charger and letting it charge for 30 minutes. With it still connected, hold the power button for 15 seconds. Let it charge for another 30 minutes. Then try to power on. Hopefully that will get you going.